# Function is not working in fpdf cell

Tags: php, fpdf

Here is my code:

```php
<?php
define('FPDF_FONTPATH','../../fpdf/font/');
require('../../fpdf/fpdf.php');
$pdf = new FPDF('L','mm','A4');
$pdf->Open();
$pdf->AddPage();

function codes($total,$mark){
    $perc = $mark/$total*100;
    if($perc >= 94){echo "A1";}    
    if($perc >= 84 && $perc<= 93){echo "A2";}
    if($perc >= 72 && $perc<= 83){echo "B1";}
    if($perc >= 60 && $perc<= 71){echo "B2";}
    if($perc >= 49 && $perc<= 59){echo "C1";}
    if($perc >= 40 && $perc<= 48){echo "C2";}
    if($perc >=0 && $perc<= 40){echo "D";}
}
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);
$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->Cell(30,8,'English',1,0,'L',0,'');
$pdf->Cell(15,8,codes(25,$fa1enga),1,0,'C',0,'');

$pdf->output();
```

But when I run this PHP code it prints:

> B2FPDF error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file

Please help me to show the text "B2" or whatever in fpdf cell.

Comment: I believe the error lies in the file that you included using require...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `codes` function will output the result of its calculation to the client instead of returning it. For FPDF to work properly, there must not be any output at all except that from FPDF itself.

Replace all occurrences of `echo` in your `codes` function with `return`.

Comment: Thank you very much, and sorry for late comments. but now it works.